# Specify open options in datasource

Tags: gdal, csv

I am using the GDAL csv driver and I can open a csv and specify geometry columns with `ogrinfo` using the `-oo` flags. However, when I want to specify these as part of another command-line tool, for example, `gdal_rasterize`, I can't seem to find the syntax to include them.

For instance, if I run

```
gdal_rasterize [--rasterize-options] myfile.csv --oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=xcol myoutputraster
```

I get an error on the `--oo` option.

Is the only way to do this using the command line to create a VRT file?

Comment: I mucked around for a while trying to use open options in `gdal_grid` and gave up and used a VRT (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/338429/2856).  Maybe an enhancement request to https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal?

Comment: Did you ever try with single dash `-oo`?

Answer (score 2):

The gdal_rasterize utility has no code for handling the open options. Compare this in ogrinfo https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/apps/gdalinfo_bin.cpp#L137

and https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/apps/gdal_rasterize_bin.cpp#L149.

Gdalinfo opens the dataset with these options

```
GDALDatasetH hDataset = GDALOpenEx(
            psOptionsForBinary->pszFilename,
            GDAL_OF_READONLY | GDAL_OF_RASTER | GDAL_OF_VERBOSE_ERROR,
            psOptionsForBinary->papszAllowInputDrivers,
            psOptionsForBinary->papszOpenOptions, nullptr);
```

but gdal_rasterize with only these

```
GDALDatasetH hInDS = GDALOpenEx(psOptionsForBinary->pszSource,
                                    GDAL_OF_VECTOR | GDAL_OF_VERBOSE_ERROR,
                                    nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Writing the open options into a VRT file is the best workaround.

The synopsis in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#synopsis is correct when it does not include open options.