# Problem processing Slovenian LiDAR DTM with GDAL (and QGIS): "too many stepY values" error

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, lidar

If I want to apply GDAL (version 2.2.3) on the LiDAR derived DTM (ASCII) from Slovenia (Link to Slovenian DTM below), I run into this error:

```
gdalinfo input.asc

ERROR 1: Ungridded dataset: At line 214, too many stepY values
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'input.asc'.
```

The files can neither be loaded into QGIS (3.4.12).

I read [here](https://www.opendem.info/opendemeu_meta_slovenia.html), that there is a XY swap in the files and [sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix)) can be used to get rid of the XY swap:

```
sort -k2 -n -k1 -t ';' input.asc -o output.xyz
```

However, after applying this to the .asc, I run into the following error:

```
gdalinfo output.xyz 

ERROR 1: Ungridded dataset: At line 1002, too many stepY values
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'output.xyz'.
```

What can I do to apply GDAL to the data?

The LiDAR can be accessed for free here: [ARSO](http://gis.arso.gov.si/evode/profile.aspx?id=atlas_voda_Lidar@Arso&culture=en-US). Here is a direct download link to a sample ASCII file (D48GK projection): [GK1_444_106.asc](http://gis.arso.gov.si/lidar/dmr1/b_32/D48GK/GK1_444_106.asc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is not a regular grid, you have missing points.  The [XYZ format description](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html) specifies "no missing value is supported".

Below is an image of a small section of the western edge of the data visualised as points showing the missing values.

[image]

To convert your data to raster, you can use `gdal_grid`.  `gdal_grid` doesn't support the full range of OGR open options syntax (i.e see the [CSV format description](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html#open-options)) so you need to create a VRT that tells `gdal_grid` how to create geometry from the X and Y fields.

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="GK1_444_106">
        <SrcDataSource>CSV:GK1_444_106.asc</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>EPSG:3794</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_1" y="field_2"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

You can then use `gdal_grid` to output a raster:

```
gdal_grid -a_srs EPSG:3912 -a nearest -txe 443999.5 445000.5 -tye 106999.65 105999.65 -outsize 1001 1000 -zfield field_3 -l GK1_444_106 GK1_444_106.vrt GK1_444_106.tif
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This helped. However, if I want to add the resulting Tiff's into a new virtual raster with `gdalbuildvrt new.vrt GK1_444_106.tif`, I get the following error: `gdalbuildvrt does not support positive NS resolution. Skipping GK1_444_106.tif`. What can I do?

Comment: See edited `gdal_grid` command. I had upper & lower y coords in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks! But if I use your given `gdal_grid` command, the process is unbelievable slow. It would take hours to produce one tif and I want to batch process this. However, if I use the command without the `-txe` and `-tye` option, the tif is produced fine in expected speed. But with this tif I run into the `gdalbuildvrt does not support positive NS resolution.` error.

Comment: I also read on other sources, like [here](https://arheologija.neocities.org/Lidar_tutorial.html), that the EPSG for D48GK projection is EPSG:3912.

Comment: I just used the CRS in your link. Using 3912 works fine for me (see edited command).  Takes about 2sec per asc->tif conversion with gdal_grid (using -txt -tye so the resolution and extent are exactly as they should be)

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to use other software? I mean CloudCompare. It is free software that will generate geotiff quickly and easily in a few clicks. I made a simple gif with sample asc file:

[image: CloudCompare]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `gdal_grid` to work: it ran for a few minutes then spat out a 0-byte file.

Horrifyingly, I found it easier and faster to

- load the sparse raster in python as a csv
- add new rows for missing data
- sort
- resave as a valid `.xyz` file
- convert to a `.tif` with `gdal_translate`

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Setup.
input_file = 'Sheet001v4.txt'
output_file = 'Sheet001v4.csv'
resolution = 10
nodata_value = -9999

# Load txt file.
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\s+', header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'z'])

# Figure out which x and y values are needed.
x_vals = set(np.arange(df.x.min(), df.x.max() + resolution, resolution))
y_vals = set(np.arange(df.y.min(), df.y.max() + resolution, resolution))

# For each x value, find any missing y values, and add a NODATA row.
dfs = [df]
for x in x_vals:
    y_vals_missing = y_vals - set(df[df.x == x].y)
    if y_vals_missing:
        df_missing = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y_vals_missing, 'z': nodata_value})
        dfs.append(df_missing)

# Build full csv, and sort to xyz spec.
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df = df.sort_values(['y', 'x'])

# Output.
df.to_csv(output_file, index=False, header=False)
```

This was for the Northern Ireland DTM dataset, code from [Fixing sparse .xyz files](https://www.gpxz.io/blog/fixing-sparse-xyz-files).