# How to use gdal_grid with ungridded .asc DTM files

Tags: gdal, ogr, vrt, gdal-grid

There was a question about processing ungridded .asc DTM files: [Problem processing Slovenian LiDAR DTM with GDAL (and QGIS): "too many stepY values" error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338374)

The answer helped a lot already, but I don't understand how you calculate -txe and -txy for the [gdal_grid](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html) command?

When I look into the [example file](http://gis.arso.gov.si/lidar/dmr1/b_32/D48GK/GK1_444_106.asc) "GK1_444_106.asc", the first point (lower left) is:

444000.00;106000.15;799.16

and the last point (upper right) is:

444999.96;106999.15;712.21

I would assume the georeferenced extents of the [gdal_grid](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html) command would be:

```
-txe <xmin> <xmax> => -txe 444000.00 444999.96

-tye <ymin> <ymax> => -tye 106000.15 106999.15
```

But in the answer it is:

```
-txe 443999.5 445000.5 -tye 106999.65 105999.65
```

1. Why was there 0.5 added (to max) and subtracted (from min) to the values (and why were they rounded)?
2. Why are the -tye values in a reversed order (max first, then min)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because 444000.00;106000.15 and 444999.96;106999.15 are the *centre* of the lower left and upper right pixels whereas the -txe and -tye refer to the extent  (i.e. centre +- 1/2 pixel width/depth).  The 0.5 is half the 1m pixel size specified in the [technical report](http://gis.arso.gov.si/evode/profile.aspx?id=atlas_voda_Lidar@Arso&culture=en-US) for the data. This is why the x max value was rounded, so as to maintain a 1m pixel width rather than 0.99996m
2. I don't know. Because it didn't work with the coordinates in -tye min, max order and resulted in an upside down output. Possibly something to do with the coordinate system but I don't know anything about the D48GK CRS